# How to pretty print a quadtree in python?

Tags: python, tree, gis, spatial, quadtree

I have some code that can make a quad tree from data points. I know how to print out binary tree with slashes, but I don't even know where to start to print/draw out a tree with 4 children instead of 2 each to be able to visualize my tree.

I've been testing it by using my search_pqtreee function.  For example, to list all the points in the northeast quadrant, I can test it by making a list like: [search_pqtree(q.ne,p) for p in points]

```
#The point import is a class for points in Cartesian coordinate systems
from point import *

class PQuadTreeNode():
    def __init__(self,point,nw=None,ne=None,se=None,sw=None):
        self.point = point
        self.nw = nw
        self.ne = ne
        self.se = se
        self.sw = sw
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.point)
    def is_leaf(self):
        return self.nw==None and self.ne==None and \
            self.se==None and self.sw==None

def search_pqtree(q, p, is_find_only=True):
    if q is None:
        return
    if q.point == p:
        if is_find_only:
            return q
        else:
            return
    dx,dy = 0,0
    if p.x >= q.point.x:
        dx = 1
    if p.y >= q.point.y:
        dy = 1
    qnum = dx+dy*2
    child = [q.sw, q.se, q.nw, q.ne][qnum]
    if child is None and not is_find_only:
        return q
    return search_pqtree(child, p, is_find_only)

def insert_pqtree(q, p):
    n = search_pqtree(q, p, False)
    node = PQuadTreeNode(point=p)
    if p.x < n.point.x and p.y < n.point.y:
        n.sw = node
    elif p.x < n.point.x and p.y >= n.point.y:
        n.nw = node
    elif p.x >= n.point.x and p.y < n.point.y:
        n.se = node
    else:
        n.ne = node

def pointquadtree(data):
    root = PQuadTreeNode(point = data[0])
    for p in data[1:]:
        insert_pqtree(root, p)
    return root

#Test
data1 = [ (2,2), (0,5), (8,0), (9,8), (7,14), (13,12), (14,13) ]

points = [Point(d[0], d[1]) for d in data1]
q = pointquadtree(points)
print([search_pqtree(q.ne, p) for p in points])
```

What I'm trying to say is if I was pretty printing a binary tree, it might look like this:

```
       (2, 2)                          
      /      \                         
   (0, 5)  (8, 0)                      
   /    \ /      \
```

Is there a way to write a function that print out 4 lines each? Or maybe print it out sideways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you classified your question with GIS and spatial, this problem made me think of a map with north-east, north-west, south-east and south-west in each corner.

A single node quadtree would simply be :

```
(0,0)
```

A two node quadtree would be :

```
      .|( 1, 1)
----( 0, 0)----
      .|.
```

With 3 nodes in depth that would go to :

```
               |      .|( 2, 2)
               |----( 1, 1)----
              .|      .|.
------------( 0, 0)------------
              .|.
               |
               |
```

I've implemented this idea, with some changes to your code to make it easier:

- I've added a trivial point class, with the `__repr__` method I needed for number formatting
- I made quadrants into a dictionary to be able to loop on them
- I thought I would need the `get_depth` method, but it's not used...

I also think that `search` and `insert` functions should be methods of the class `PQuadTreeNode`, but I leave it to you as an exercise :)

The implementation works with the following steps:

- If the quadtree is a leaf, its map is the central point
- Get the maps of the 4 quadrants (if empty, it's a dot)
- Normalize them using the size of the largest, and puts them near the center of the parent
- Combine the 4 quadrants with the quadtree point at the center.

This is of course higly recursive, and I didn't made any attempt at optimization.
If numbers have a length greater than 2 (like 100 or -10), you can adjust the `num_length` variable.

```
num_length = 2
num_fmt = '%' + str(num_length) + 'd'

class Point():
    def __init__(self,x=None,y=None):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __repr__(self):
        return '(' + (num_fmt % self.x) + ',' + (num_fmt % self.y) + ')'

def normalize(corner, quadmap, width, height):
    old_height = len(quadmap)
    old_width = len(quadmap[0])
    if old_height == height and old_width == width:
        return quadmap
    else:
        blank_width = width - old_width
        if corner == 'nw':
            new = [' '*width for i in range(height - old_height)]
            for line in quadmap:
                new.append(' '*blank_width + line)
        elif corner == 'ne':
            new = [' '*width for i in range(height - old_height)]
            for line in quadmap:
                new.append(line + ' '*blank_width)
        elif corner == 'sw':
            new = []
            for line in quadmap:
                new.append(' '*blank_width + line)
            for i in range(height - old_height):
                new.append(' '*width)
        elif corner == 'se':
            new = []
            for line in quadmap:
                new.append(line + ' '*blank_width)
            for i in range(height - old_height):
                new.append(' '*width)
        return new

class PQuadTreeNode():
    def __init__(self,point,nw=None,ne=None,se=None,sw=None):
        self.point = point
        self.quadrants = {'nw':nw, 'ne':ne, 'se':se, 'sw':sw}

    def __repr__(self):
        return '\n'.join(self.get_map())

    def is_leaf(self):
        return all(q == None for q in self.quadrants.values())

    def get_depth(self):
        if self.is_leaf():
            return 1
        else:
            return 1 + max(q.get_depth() if q else 0 for q in self.quadrants.values())

    def get_map(self):
        if self.is_leaf():
            return [str(self.point)]
        else:
            subquadmaps = {
                sqn:sq.get_map() if sq else ['.']
                for sqn, sq
                in self.quadrants.items()
            }
            subheight = max(len(map) for map in subquadmaps.values())
            subwidth = max(len(mapline) for map in subquadmaps.values() for mapline in map)
            subquadmapsnorm = {
                sqn:normalize(sqn, sq, subwidth, subheight)
                for sqn, sq
                in subquadmaps.items()
            }
            map = []
            for n in range(subheight):
                map.append(subquadmapsnorm['nw'][n] + '|' + subquadmapsnorm['ne'][n])
            map.append('-' * (subwidth-num_length-1) + str(self.point) + '-' * (subwidth-num_length-1))
            for n in range(subheight):
                map.append(subquadmapsnorm['sw'][n] + '|' + subquadmapsnorm['se'][n])
            return map

def search_pqtree(q, p, is_find_only=True):
    if q is None:
        return
    if q.point == p:
        if is_find_only:
            return q
        else:
            return
    dx,dy = 0,0
    if p.x >= q.point.x:
        dx = 1
    if p.y >= q.point.y:
        dy = 1
    qnum = dx+dy*2
    child = [q.quadrants['sw'], q.quadrants['se'], q.quadrants['nw'], q.quadrants['ne']][qnum]
    if child is None and not is_find_only:
        return q
    return search_pqtree(child, p, is_find_only)

def insert_pqtree(q, p):
    n = search_pqtree(q, p, False)
    node = PQuadTreeNode(point=p)
    if p.x < n.point.x and p.y < n.point.y:
        n.quadrants['sw'] = node
    elif p.x < n.point.x and p.y >= n.point.y:
        n.quadrants['nw'] = node
    elif p.x >= n.point.x and p.y < n.point.y:
        n.quadrants['se'] = node
    else:
        n.quadrants['ne'] = node

def pointquadtree(data):
    root = PQuadTreeNode(point = data[0])
    for p in data[1:]:
        insert_pqtree(root, p)
    return root

#Test
data1 = [ (2,2), (0,5), (8,0), (9,8), (7,14), (13,12), (14,13) ]

points = [Point(d[0], d[1]) for d in data1]
q = pointquadtree(points)
print(q)
```

With your example data:

```
                               |               |      .|(14,13)
                               |               |----(13,12)----
                               |        ( 7,14)|      .|.
                               |------------( 9, 8)------------
                               |              .|.
                               |               |
                        ( 0, 5)|               |
----------------------------( 2, 2)----------------------------
                              .|( 8, 0)
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
                               |
```

Tell me if you find it useful !

Comment: This was super helpful, thank you for the clear explanation!